# Parse Connection Times out only for one specific function

Tags: javascript, ios, swift, parse-platform

Below is my cloud code in which I am attempting to use to create a Friend Database, Both the first and the third function work fine however the AcceptFriendRequest function times out as if there is no server there with the error code 100.  I am very lost as this happens 100% of the time.  All help is appreciated.

```
Parse.Cloud.define("AddFriendRequest", function (request, response) {

var FriendRequest = Parse.Object.extend("FriendsIncoming");

var FRequest = new FriendRequest();

var user = request.user;

var query = new Parse.Query(Parse.User);
query.equalTo("username", request.params.username);
query.find({
    success: function (people) {
        if(people.length == 0)
        {
            response.success(-5);
            return;
        }

        var person = people[0];
        FRequest.set("OwnerID", user.id);
        FRequest.set("TargetFriend", person.id);
        FRequest.set("Status", 0);

        var query = new Parse.Query("FriendsIncoming");
        query.equalTo("OwnerID", user.id);
        query.equalTo("TargetFriendID", person.id);
        query.find({
            success: function (results) {

                if (results.length > 0) {
                    response.success(1);
                    return;
                }
                FRequest.save(null, {
                    success: function (Friend) {
                        response.success(2);
                    },
                    error: function (Friend, error) {
                        response.error(3);
                    }
                });
                response.error(-2);

            },
            error: function () {
                response.error(-1);
            }
        });
    }
    ,
    error: function (Friend, error) {
        response.error(-4);
    }

});


});

Parse.Cloud.define("AcceptFriendRequest", function (request, response) {


var user = request.user;

var query = new Parse.Query("FriendsIncoming");
query.equalTo("OwnerID", user.id);
query.equalTo("TargetFriendID", request.params.TargetFriendID);
query.find({
    success: function (results) {

        if (results.length > 0) {

            response.success(1);
            return;
        }
        FRequest.save(null, {
            success: function (Friend) {
                response.success(2);
            },
            error: function (Friend, error) {
                response.error(3);
            }
        });
        response.error(-2);

    },
    error: function () {
        response.error(-1);
    }
});
});




Parse.Cloud.define("RetrieveFriends", function (request, response) {

var query = new Parse.Query("FriendsAccepted");
var results = [];


query.find().then(function (Friends) {
for (var i = 0; i < Friends.length; i++) {
results.push(Friends[i]);
}

// success has been moved inside the callback for query.find()
response.success(results);
}, function (error) {
// Make sure to catch any errors, otherwise you may see a "success/error not called" error in Cloud Code.
response.error("Could not retrieve Posts, error " + error.code + ": " + error.message);
});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the FRequest in the AcceptFriendRequest is not initialized...
add this in the inside of the function. The timeout on parse.com is 15 seconds for cloud function and for afterSave 3 secs. They might changed it though cause they are shutting down

```
var FriendRequest = Parse.Object.extend("FriendsIncoming");
var FRequest = new FriendRequest();
```